# find the length of an arc (line integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Find the length of the plane curve arc $\gamma $: $y=\ln(x)-\frac{x^{2}}{8}$ which projects itself on the $x$ axis in the interval $(2,5)$

I'm learning line integrals so I tried to use that.

$l(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}ds$ where $ds=\sqrt{y'(x)^{2}}dx$ with $2<x<5$ so I have $$l(\gamma)=\int_{2}^{5}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{4})dx = \ln\frac{5}{2}-\frac{21}{8}$$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: $ds =\sqrt{1+y'^2} $ not $\sqrt{y'^2}.$

Comment: You are right.I have y=f(x) so the parametrization would be x=t and y=f(t), right?

Comment: Yes.  And I should have a $dx$ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard bit of algebraic acrobatics which is common in line-integral textbook problems.   They work things out so the middle term changes sign when you add one:

$$1+\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{4}\right)^2 =
1+\frac{1}{x^2} -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2}{16}$$

$$\frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2}{16} = \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{4}\right)^2.$$

So your integrand should have the minus changed to a plus.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your integrand under the root is negative, so indeed $y'(x) = \frac1x - \frac{x}4$ and then
$$
\ell(\gamma)
 = \int_2^5 \sqrt{\left(\frac1x - \frac{x}4 \right)^2} dx
 = \int_2^5 \left|\frac1x - \frac{x}4 \right| dx
 = \int_2^5 \left(\frac{x}4  - \frac1x\right) dx
 = \frac{21}{8} - \ln \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)
$$